# change image source based on variables

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there a way to change the source of an HTML image using javascript based on variables? I am thinking of something like this:

```
var image = 1;

if(image=1) {
    document.getElementById('myImage').src = "images/one.png";
} else if(image=2) {
    document.getElementById('myImage').src = "images/two.png";
} else {
    window.alert("You have a weird variable value");
}
```

Please tell me how I can get this to work using an if...then or switch statement.

Comment: you can easily check to see if this works yourself: jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is an assignment. An assignment statement evaluates as itself. So `if(image=1)` means "assign 1 to image, then if 1 is true…". (`1` is always a true value).

To compare two values use `===` (or `==` if you want type munging).

```
if (image === 1) {
```

and

```
} else if (image === 2) {
```